# Airflow upload Pandas dataframe to Redshift table

Tags: pandas, airflow, amazon-redshift

I would like to use Airflow to populate a table in redshift. The data that I want to insert is in the form of a pandas dataframe, although I could write it to a csv or any other format.

I am looking at the documentation for the [RedshiftSQLOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/2.4.0/operators/redshift.html) but the inserts are hardcoded, I don't know if there is a way to bulk upload data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redshift operator also defines a hook which gives you access to a SQL engine -- https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/2.4.0/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/redshift/index.html#airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.redshift.RedshiftSQLHook.

You'll be well advised to use the pandas `to_sql` function wherein you specify the connection parameter to effect the insert.

```
redshift_hook = RedshiftSQLHook(...)
engine = redshift_hook.get_sqlalchemy_engine()

df.to_sql(..., conn=engine)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked fine. The only thing is that I don't see the column names when I query the redshift table that I created and inserted into, is this normal?

Comment: nope. if your dataframe is malformed, then this issue might be there, but I have seen column names come up correctly.